# What port numbers for Spring-RMI-Callback

Tags: java, spring, callback, port, rmi

I am working on an application built upon a spring 2.0 stack with a rich client connecting to a server through RMI. The server is listening for incoming connections on an RMI registry which port has been set in the spring descriptor:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="service.context" />
    <property name="service" ref="service.context" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="myApp.context.IServerContext" />
    <property name="registryPort" value="${server.port}" />
</bean>
```

When the connection happens, we also establish an RMI Callback capability with a class that extends `UnicastRemoteObject`.

But I cannot find a way to specify on which port (or range of ports) this connection will establish. That was not a problem until my corporate network has decided to implement strong firewall policies.

Now I would like to know (or decide) what ports will be used so that they can be declared in the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the port number via super(port) in the constructor of the callback class.